# Vector de n componentes

Tags: fortran

He intentado construir un programa que genere un vector de 1000 componentes, pero luego no hace nada. El código es este, muy sencillo:

```
program vector

    real:: r(10000)
    call random_number(r)

end program
```

Comment: ¿Y qué esperas que haga el programa? Si no le das más instrucciones después de llamar a `random_number` el programa finalizará su ejecución.

Comment: Ah vale, es decir, tendría que declarar "r=r(10000)" no?

Comment: O cuál sería instrucción para que generase?

Comment: Así no funciona SOes. Respecto a mi ultimo comentario, investiga como hacer bucles en [tag:fortran] y despues si no te sale, preguntar con el codigo que tengas. Este codigo de ahora y no tener nada es parecido. Un saludo

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Cuanto termine de hacer el bucle si no sale nada, vuelvo a preguntar. Gracias de nuevo lois.

Comment: Elimina esta pregunta y haz la nueva si es necesario. Así como está será cerrada por muy amplia. Un saludo

Comment: ¿cómo se borra la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Esto no intenta ser una respuesta ya que tu pregunta no especifica qué esperas que haga el programa... pero este contenido ni entra en un comentario ni tampoco sería legible.

El programa funciona y hace exactamente aquello que se le pide... un ejemplo:

```
program vector

    real:: r(5)
    print *,r
    call random_number(r)
    print *,r

end program
```

Este programa genera, en mi caso, la siguiente salida:

```
0.00000000E+00   0.00000000E+00   0.00000000E+00   0.00000000E+00   2.64840121E+22   
0.997559547      0.566824675      0.965915322      0.747927666      0.367390871
```

Ahí se ve como los valores del vector han cambiado después de la llamada a `random_number`.

No se qué esperas que haga el programa, pero de momento tu cometido de generar números pseudoaleatorios funciona.

Por cierto, considera establecer una semilla inicial para evitar secuencias cíclicas.